# python code to echo ajax requests

Tags: python, ajax

I am looking for simple echo server implementation in python. I googled it, but all the results were dependant on external libraries. I am sending a string to python from html:

```
$.post("server.py", 'blabla')
```

What I would like python to do is something like this:

```
wait for request:
    send_back('OK: ' + uppercase(request.data))
```

How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something to process your URLs. Have you tried [Web.py](http://webpy.org/)

It can get you started quickly.

```
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:        
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name: 
            name = 'World'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```